# AutoUpdate.dll & AutoUpdate.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to compile a program that I am not familiar with using VS2013 express version. When compiled, it says cannot open incluse file "afxres.h". Some told me this could be fixed by replacing afxres.h with windows.h . Tried it. However, it seems to cause another linking error. It says cannot open input file 'AutoUpdate.lib'. can't find AutoUpdate.lib in my computer, but instead, I have AutoUpdate.dll included in the solution. Still struggling to solve this problem. Can anybody help me to compile this program? It'd be really appreciated. Thanks.